# Convert Multiple Text into QR Code Image

Tags: android, qr-code

I have read some article that describe using ZXing to convert text into QR Code (ImageView).

But i have 3 EditText field to make this. Is it possible ? How to accomplish this ?

Comment: Concatenate them to one string, maybe? Depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Add them to one string with separators

```
String qrstring = editext1.getstring().toText+ "%" + editext2.getstring().toText + "#" + editext3.getstring().toText
```

and send this final string to the qr encoder

and use corresponding logic to decode it